# Check if a JSON array is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know from the first look it sounds like duplicate question but i don't think it is...

I am receiving back a JSON array as:

```
var test1 = [] ;
```

or

```
var test2 = [{},{},{}] ;  //This is empty
```

I have no problem finding out if `test1` is empty.

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject(test1)
```

My problem is with the `test2`... 
Please note that in some cases the test2 might return something like:

```
var test2 = [{"a":1},{},{}] ;  //All these are not empty
var test2 = [{},{"a":1},{}] ;  //All these are not empty
var test2 = [{},{},{"a":1}] ;  //All these are not empty
```

The above scenarios shouldn't be counted as empty.I've tried to use `.length` but it's not helping as the length is always 3... Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you saying that it should only return true if the array is empty or the array only contains objects without keys?

Comment: Why not just use this if statement: `test2[0].length===0&&test[1].length===0&&test[2].length===0` i know it s crude but whatever

Comment: `length` is not a valid property on an object.

Comment: +1 Evan, if you use .length to an object you will just get an undefined error . @ Evan Trimboli  i just need to capture the scenario were test2 is [{},{},{}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function isArrayEmpty(array) {
    return array.filter(function(el) {
        return !jQuery.isEmptyObject(el);
    }).length === 0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vNt3h/)

Passes all of your tests.

A pure JavaScript solution would be to replace `!jQuery.isEmptyObject(el)` with `Object.keys(el).length !== 0`

Edit: Using **[Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?redirect=no)**

```
function isArrayEmpty(array) {
    return array.every(function(el) {
        return jQuery.isEmptyObject(el);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those playing at home, a non jQuery solution:

```
var test2 = [{a: 1},{},{}] ;  //This is empty

function isEmpty(val) {
    var len = val.length,
        i;

    if (len > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if (!emptyObject(val[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function emptyObject(o) {
    for (var key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isEmpty(test2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Without JQuery: using `Array.filter`<sup>**1**</sup> and `Object.keys`<sup>**2**</sup>:

```
function JSONEmpty(obj){
    return !obj.length || 
           !obj.filter(function(a){return Object.keys(a).length;}).length;
}
// usage
JSONEmpty([{"a":1},{},{}]);  //=> false
JSONEmpty([{},{"a":1},{}]);  //=> false
JSONEmpty([{},{},{"a":1}]);  //=> false
JSONEmpty([]);               //=> true
JSONEmpty([{},{},{}]);       //=> true
```

**update 2018** [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are now supported by all modern browsers, so like [himel-nag-rana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/926943/himel-nag-rana) stipulated, you can also use:

```
const JSONEmpty = obj => !obj.length || !obj.filter(a => Object.keys(a).length).length;
```

<sup>**1**</sup> [**More info**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
<sup>**2**</sup> [**More info**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)  (links contain shims for older browsers)

Comment: Probably worth noting the browser compatibility for `Object.keys` and `Array.filter`.

Comment: a more shorter version with arrow function ````isJSONArrayEmpty(obj) {
    return !obj.length ||
           !obj.filter(a => Object.keys(a).length).length;
  }````

Comment: @HimelNagRana I'm pretty sure arrow functions were not or partly implemented in most browsers back in august 2013

Comment: @KooiInc, yes  of course that came much later. But my point of adding this was just to add to the solution so that when devs from 2018 comes they get a shorter/updated version. Nothing else. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I come with this solution without jQuery:

```
function isEmpty(x) {
   for(var i in x) {
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple...

```
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(test2[0]) && jQuery.isEmptyObject(test2[1]) && jQuery.isEmptyObject(test2[2])))
    // do something
```

Comment: What if the array has 4 elements?

Comment: Yeah i was lazy but you could very easily implement this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try use function like

```
function isEmptyObject (test) {
    for (var i in test) {
        if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(test[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take: turn the array into a set and check for size.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
var mySet = new Set(myArray);
console.log(mySet.size === 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

check by looping each values in array and return error
Try

```
for(i=0;js_array[i]!=null;i++)
{
  if(js_array[i]=="")
  { 
    alert("Empty");
  }
}
```

Comment: This will always return false since the condition is using an assignment to a falsey value.