# JSON should be empty, but contains string "[]"

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have checked most of the posted questions, but what I am doing now is to check if JSON is empty. However, after debugging with Chrome, the JSON object contains only "[]" and is not empty. So if there is a case where JSON doesn't have value, but a "[]", how can we check if it is empty then (which aparently it is)?

Comment: What do you mean by «JSON does not have value»?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a JSON array is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396073/check-if-a-json-array-is-empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is an abbreviation for JavaScript Object Notation. An empty object is []. This makes it possible to set values in that object, which would be impossible if it would have been empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(jsonObject)) {
    //code here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
{"ABC":[ "test":"test1", "test2":"test2", ]}
```

then U can Check it as **Key.length** or other length of array function and perform check

if(ABC.length>0)
then ..

For JavaScript Key.length works...